# VBA How do I loop an instr function using a string variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I just started learning VBA and I am trying to get an if and loop function to work together.
I basically want to search for @ in column A and if there is @ then = ok, if not= "not valid".
I get it to work for one row but to loop it for an entire column. Please kindly advise. 
ps. please be indulgent with my ugly first timer code.

Thank you in advance,
Christine

```
Sub help()

    Dim email As String

    email = InStr(email, "@")

    Do While email = InStr(email, "@")
        Cells(email, 1).Value = email
        If email = 0 Then
            Cells(email, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = "Not valid"
        Else
            Cells(email, 1).Offset(, 1).Value = "ok"
        End If 
    Loop

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI - you can do this check without needing VBA.  I/we still answered so you can help learn VBA (as you see there are many ways to skin a cell) , just wanted to let you know there's a simple formula solution too.

Comment: Conditional formatting can also solve this with `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*" & "." & "*" & "@" & "*" & ".com",A1),"Correct Format",),"Wrong Format")
`

Comment: (As kind of hinted in @Maldred's post, be aware that with your current formula, if there's an entry of `email@` this will return as Valid...even though you're missing the `.com/edu/org/mil`)

Comment: I need to correct my formula actually, it requires a `"."` somewhere before the `"@"` and it also required a `".com"`. Corrected formula would be: `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("*" & "@" & "*" & ".",A1),"Correct Format",),"Wrong Format")` This will take anything along the lines of `*@*.*`

Comment: @BruceWayne I realise its easier without VBA but as I am learning it I need to know how so I deeply appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set a range, then loop through that range:

```
Sub help()
Dim email As String
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range 'New
Dim lastRow as Long 'New

lastRow = Range("A"& rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow) 'Adjust as necessary

For Each cel In rng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, "@") > 0 Then
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Ok"
    Else
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Not Valid"
    End If
   ' OR as @JohnyL points out, you can do the above in line. 
   ' Just comment out/remove the above `If` statement and uncomment below
   ' cel.Offset(0, 1) = IIf(InStr(1, cel.Value, "@") > 0, "Ok", "Not Valid")
Next cel

End Sub
```

Here's a super-short macro that may work, depending on how your data is laid out:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
rng.Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(""@"",A2)),""Not Valid"",""Yes"")"
rng.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can create a User Defined Function.  Enter this code in a Workbook Module:

```
Function validate_email(cel As Range) As String
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "@") > 0 Then
    validate_email = "Valid"
Else
    validate_email = "Not Valid"
End If
End Function
```

And in cell, say `B20`, just do `=validate_email(A20)` and I'll check for you.  This has the advantage of being able to be run on any cell, and not have to edit your macro's range(s).

[image]

Also, just to note, you **don't need VBA** for this, you can simply use the formula `=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("@",A2)),"Not Valid","Yes")` in Column B and drag down.

And finally, as I mentioned in the comments, this doesn't really check email validity.  However, for your question, it works.  See [this page](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/validate-email-vba.html), or [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eaa099b6-3bfe-45f0-b391-c1816e823261/vba-function-for-checking-email-syntax-validity?forum=accessdev), or simply search [VBA email validation](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+email+validation) for more ways to check if the email address is proper.

Comment: Nice, just `Set rng` dynamically to last row with data

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @ShaiRado - Good thinking, edited with the `lastRow`.

Comment: You went "All-Out" on this post ;)

Comment: You could use shorter code in `For..Each`: `cel.Offset(0, 1) = IIf(InStr(1, cel.Value, "@") > 0, "Ok", "Not Valid")`

Comment: Wow this is super cool. The last row part is very exciting. I do not understand how the user defined function works, will read up on it!

Comment: @JohnyL - Oh for sure.  However, I wanted to keep it as "explicit" and obvious as I could since OP is learning VBA.  I could also combine my `lastRow` into a single row and remove the need for the variable.

Comment: @BruceWayne I don't think it will cause any harm if OP will get to know a myriad of ways to write VBA, right? :)

Comment: @BruceWayne And I guess we could make with one-liner: `For Each cel in Range("A2:A" & Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count)` :)

Comment: @JohnyL - Yep yep yep! I've edited your original comment in to the post. :D  -- Good call with `CurrentRegion` too (although I tend to hesitate with that without knowing exactly what the OP data looks like, I've gotten funky results with `CurrentRegion` before).

Comment: @BruceWayne And if OP's range starts from A2, we could get it even shorter: `For Each cel in Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Colums(1)` :-)

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, `CurrentRegion` is tricky to work with, so we have to know the exact shape of OP's range. Anyway, `CurrentRegion` is sometimes the best way to get to know the last row/column when you don't know which column to select for `End` property.

Comment: Because both alternatives are string literals, you could make the UDF a single assignment using `IIf` - `validate_email = IIf(InStr(1, cel.Value, "@") > 0, "Valid", "Not Valid")`. This is a perfect example of `IIf` being put to good use. If you read this and think "oh nice, I'll start using `IIf` for every ternary condition now!" just know that `IIf` executes both the true and false parts, so that's why I said "because both alternatives are string literals" - DO NOT use `IIf` if either branch has side-effects!

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it a slightly different way:

```
Sub foo()
Dim email As String
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'change the Sheet1 to whatever
For i = 2 To lastrow 'loop through from row 2 to Last
    email = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value, "@") 'do the Instr
    If email = 0 Then Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Not Valid"
    If email > 0 Then Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Ok"
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you but the code does not run I get an error "424" my mac is In french so translation would be something like "object required". Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: You need to change Sheet1 to Sheets("NameofSheet") or even to ActiveSheet..

Comment: Great now its running perfectly with activesheet ! I tried to mark your solution valid too but it seems I can only mark one as accepted (yes Im new to stackoverflow too!:)

Answer (score 2):

You are after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub help()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' get last row with data in column A

For i = 1 To LastRow
    If InStr(Range("A" & i).Value2, "@") > 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).Value2 = "ok"
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Value2 = "Not Valid"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `A19` downwards, this is a possible solution:

```
Option Explicit

Sub help()

    Dim email       As String
    Dim rngCell     As Range

    Set rngCell = Range("A19")

    Do While rngCell <> vbNullString
        If InStr(rngCell, "@") Then
            rngCell.Offset(, 1) = "Ok"
        Else
            rngCell.Offset(, 1) = "Not valid"
        End If

        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that is very useful and clear code for me to understand:)